Save compressed DICOM image without having to temporally save uncompressed DICOM
I have a DicomInterface class that inherits from DcmDataset class. After setting the DICOM tags, I want to save the DICOM image with JPEG Process 14 transfer syntax. If I first save the DICOM file with Little Endian Explicit VR transfer syntax, then load the file and assign to a new dataset, then I can save the new dataset into a DICOM file with JPEG Process 14 transfer syntax.
void DicomInterface::SaveDicom(const QString &patient_name,
                   const QString &study_number,
                   const QString &img_name){
  DcmFileFormat file_format(this);
  std::string dcm_path = GetSaveDicomPath(patient_name, study_number, img_name);
  DJEncoderRegistration::registerCodecs(); // Compress
  DJ_RPLossless representation_parameter;

  // Save temporal dicom with EXS_LittleEndianExplicit
  file_format.saveFile(dcm_path.c_str(),
                   EXS_LittleEndianExplicit);
                   
  // Load the temporal file
  OFCondition status = file_format.loadFile(dcm_path.c_str());
  DcmDataset *dataset = file_format.getDataset();

  // Save compressed Dicom
  status = dataset->chooseRepresentation(EXS_JPEGProcess14SV1,
                                        &representation_parameter);
  status = file_format.saveFile(dcm_path.c_str(),
                                        EXS_JPEGProcess14SV1);
  if (status.bad()) {
    qDebug() << "\n Error: cannot write DICOM file (" << status.text() << ")";
  }
  DJEncoderRegistration::cleanup();
}

However, when I try to save the compressed DICOM without the intermediate saving step. The operation is not successful and shows this error "Pixel representation not found".
void DicomInterface::SaveDicom(const QString &patient_name,
                   const QString &study_number,
                   const QString &img_name){
  DcmFileFormat file_format(this);
  std::string dcm_path = GetSaveDicomPath(patient_name, study_number, img_name);
  DJEncoderRegistration::registerCodecs(); // Compress
  DJ_RPLossless representation_parameter;
  status = chooseRepresentation(EXS_JPEGProcess14SV1,
                                        &representation_parameter);
  status = file_format.saveFile(dcm_path.c_str(),
                                        EXS_JPEGProcess14SV1);
  if (status.bad()) {
    qDebug() << "\n Error: cannot write DICOM file (" << status.text() << ")";
  }

  DJEncoderRegistration::cleanup();
}

How can I save the compressed DICOM without having to temporally save the uncompressed DICOM?

It seems that you did not consider that DcmFileFormat file_format(this); creates a deep copy of the DICOM data set that you pass to the constructor (see documentation). Calling status = chooseRepresentation(...); in your second sample code therefore does not work on the DICOM data set that is managed by file_format.
I also wonder whether it really makes sense to derive DicomInterface from DcmDataset (as you wrote in your first sentence).

Thanks for your answer! In the DicomInterface, there are other methods to set the DICOM tags. Instead of having a dataset as a member, I derive the class from DcmDataset and use the DcmDataset methods directly.
